# PGFPlots bug between trim axis, fill betwen, and error marks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween, error-bars

Using PGFPlots to plot a datapoint with error bars, in addition to using the `fill between` function, as well as the TikZ `trim axis left, trim axis right` keys, I get a weird bug where the error marks (red) are detached from the error bars, and seemingly placed at random (chaning the coordinates of the blue box also changes the location of the red marks).
How do I fix this behaviour?

A minimal working example is below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
        
    \pgfplotsset{
        plotStyle/.style={
            color=black,
            only marks,
            mark=square*,
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir=both,
            y fixed=1,
            error bar style={very thick},
            error mark options={very thick, mark size=2pt,rotate=90, red}
        },
    }

    \begin{axis}
    
    \addplot [name path = a, draw = none] coordinates {
        (1, 0)
        (1, 2)
    };
    \addplot [name path = b, draw = none] coordinates {
        (2, 0)
        (2, 2)
    };
    \addplot[blue] fill between [of=a and b];
 
    \addplot[plotStyle] coordinates {
        (0, 0)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Commenting out either the `[trim axis left, trim axis right]` or `\addplot[blue] fill between [of=a and b];` will make the error marks be in the right place, but as it is above, the following plot is compiled:

[image: image showing bug with misplaced error marks]

Comment: The effect also appears if you add only `trim left=` as option with different values. With 0cm as value, the error marks are at the correct place. However, I did not find that changing the coordinates for the blue rectangle affect the position of the error marks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
Shifting the rectangle y-coordinates make the error marks change position for me, e.g. with the rectangle spanning (1, -1) (2, 1), or (1, 1) (2, 3), makes the error marks get new positions.
For now, I guess I'll resort to using the \fill (coord) rectangle (coord); command instead with manual plot limits, as I luckily have a simple fill shape.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what the reason for the problem is, but it has something to do with the fact that a tikzpicture is nested in a node that draws the error bar marks. Here is a workaround - I can not say if it works in all cases or if it breaks in other ways:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis right]
\begin{axis}
\addplot[name path=a, draw=none] coordinates {(1.5, 1) (1.5, 2)}; \addplot[name path=b, draw=none] coordinates {(2, 1) (2, 2)}; \addplot[blue] fill between [of=a and b];
%% Problematic error bar
\addplot[red,error bars/y dir=both, error bars/y fixed=1] coordinates {(0,1)};
%%% Code from pfgplots.code.tex used to draw half errorbar (with color and coordinates inserted)
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}{\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}{\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
\draw[cyan, yshift={\pgfplotbarshift}] (0.2,1) -- (0.2,2) node[pos=1,sloped,allow upside down] {%
                \expandafter\tikz\expandafter[\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts]{%
                    \expandafter\pgfuseplotmark\expandafter{\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
                    \pgfusepath{stroke}}%
            };
%% draw without problems:
\draw[green] (0.4,1) -- (0.4,2) node[pos=1, sloped, allow upside down] {$\vert$};
%% minimal draw with problems:
\draw[orange] (0.6,1) -- (0.6,2) node[pos=1, sloped, allow upside down] {\tikz{$\vert$}};
%% Naive try that actually worked
\draw[pink] (0.8,1) -- (0.8,2) node[pos=1, sloped, allow upside down] {\tikz[trim left=0pt, trim right=0pt]{$\vert$}};
%% Working error bar
\addplot[red, error bars/y dir=both, error bars/y fixed=1, 
  error bars/error mark options={rotate=90, trim left=0pt, trim right=0pt}] coordinates {(1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with several error bars where some has detached ends]